# Should I run rsop as administrator or as domain user?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, group-policy, diagnostic

I have to diagnostic some AD policy on a windows7 client. So I want run rsop but I dont know if I have to run it as administrator (local) or as domain limited user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the information you need. If you need only those policies applied to the user, run as unprivileged user, but if you also need those policies applied to the computer, you must run it with administrator privileges.

You can also get applied policies to a different account using the /USER  modifier running the gpresult command as administrator.